# How to get captcha img src with Ruby and Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to write simple crawler, that would be filling 2 input fields. The page has an `img` element. Through Chrome developer mode I can see that `img` has `src` attribute. But after fetching the page the `src` attribute is gone. How do I get over this?
Code:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Chrome'

page = agent.get('https://ercdmd.ru/?gpay')

form = page.forms.first

form.gpay_abon = '00-0000000000'

captcha = page.at('#img_captcha')

pp captcha
```

Output:

```
#(Element:0x15e90ec {
  name = "img",
  attributes = [ #(Attr:0x15e8c14 { name = "id", value = "img_captcha" })]
  })
```

My idea is to get invoice by a query through Telegram bot. Since there is a captcha I thought that I could read captcha image `src` with Mechanize to send that image through Telegram. Than, I would input digits that I can see on image and send in back to Mechanize to fill second input field. But now I am stuck.
Is there an other way to get invoice from that source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm looking at that page, the captcha url would be:

```
captcha_url = "https://ercdmd.ru/captcha.php?time=#{Time.now.to_i}000"
```

Give that a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thank a lot! That's exactly what I needed.